# How do you open another colorbox after it's closed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

How does one open another colorbox after it's closed?

Here's what i've done so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
     $(".signup, .load, #loop a[href='#signup_box'], .signup_sidebar").colorbox({
        inline : true,
        innerWidth : 600,
        innerHeight : 600,
        escKey : false,
        arrowKey : false,
        fixed : true,
        onClosed:function(){
          interrupt();
        }
      })
    //...    
    interrupt = function ($) {
      $('#footer .stage .interrupt').colorbox({
        inline : true,
        innerWidth :  '600px',
        innerHeight : '600px',
        escKey :      false,
        arrowKey :    false,
        fixed :       true
      });
    };
});
```

Whenever i initialize this in a document i get an error saying that colorbox isn't defined. I'm thinking this is a scoping issue but i'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Change `interrupt` definition to

```
interrupt = function () { ... }
```

Not sure why you're expecting `$` as parameter but it's not necessary and is causing problems.

Comment: You're right. i should have included it in the script. I've updated the code surrounding my function call

Comment: I can't get jquery.colorbox to be defined.